# SVG Animate Planes Around Globe

Tags: css, svg, 3d

**[CodePen Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdyOaj)**

I am trying to get this plane animation so that the planes fly around the globe:

[image: planes]

I have added the globe to the code using a `<circle>` element, but I am not sure how to mask the backside of the planes so that they appear to be flying "around" the globe.

[image: planes-globe]

I have tried using `position:relative` together with `z-indexes` in order to achieve that the globe has a "closer" position than the back of the plane, but I have not been able to pull this off.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

**CODE**

```
<svg width="300px" height="300px">
  <defs>
    <path id="svg-half-plane"
          d=" M 0,-5
             A 1,1 0 0 1 1,-4
             L 1,-1 5,1 5,2 1,1 1,3 2,4 2,5 0,4
             Z"
          ></path>

    <symbol viewBox="0 0 10 10" id="svg-plane" overflow="visible">
      <use xlink:href="#svg-half-plane"></use>
      <use xlink:href="#svg-half-plane" transform="scale(-1, 1)"></use>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
  <g class="sky" transform="translate(150, 150)">

    <circle class="globe" cx="0" cy="0" r="100" />

    <g class="plane-container" transform="rotate(289)">
      <use class="plane" xlink:href="#svg-plane" width="50" height="50"></use>
    </g>

    <g class="plane-container" transform="rotate(129)">
      <use class="plane delay-1" xlink:href="#svg-plane" width="50" height="50"></use>
    </g>

    <g class="plane-container" transform="rotate(37.5)">
      <use class="plane delay-2" xlink:href="#svg-plane" width="50" height="50"></use>
    </g>

    <g class="plane-container" transform="rotate(57.5)">
      <use class="plane delay-3" xlink:href="#svg-plane" width="50" height="50"></use>
    </g>

    <g class="plane-container" transform="rotate(-37.5)">
      <use class="plane delay-4" xlink:href="#svg-plane" width="50" height="50"></use>
    </g>


  </g>
</svg>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #222;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

svg {
  display          : block;
  background-color : #555;
  shape-rendering  : crispEdges;
}

.plane-container {
  -webkit-perspective : 900px;
  -ms-perspective     : 900px;
  perspective         : 900px;
  z-index:            : 3;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flyaround {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform : rotateX(0deg) translateZ(140px) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform         : rotateX(0deg) translateZ(140px) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    fill              : #eee;
    opacity           : 1.0;
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform : rotateX(180deg) translateZ(140px) scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    transform         : rotateX(180deg) translateZ(140px) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    fill              : #eee;
    opacity           : 0.5;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform : rotateX(360deg) translateZ(140px) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform         : rotateX(360deg) translateZ(140px) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    fill              : #eee;
    opacity           : 1.0;
  }
}

@keyframes flyaround {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform : rotateX(0deg) translateZ(140px) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    -ms-transform     : rotateX(0deg) translateZ(140px) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform         : rotateX(0deg) translateZ(140px) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    fill              : #eee;
    opacity           : 1.0;
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform : rotateX(180deg) translateZ(140px) scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    -ms-transform     : rotateX(180deg) translateZ(140px) scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    transform         : rotateX(180deg) translateZ(140px) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    fill              : #eee;
    opacity           : 0.5;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform : rotateX(360deg) translateZ(140px) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    -ms-transform     : rotateX(360deg) translateZ(140px) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform         : rotateX(360deg) translateZ(140px) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    fill              : #eee;
    opacity           : 1.0;
  }
}

.plane {
  fill              : none;
  -webkit-animation : flyaround 2500ms infinite linear;
  animation         : flyaround 2500ms infinite linear;
}

.delay-1 { -webkit-animation-delay: 123ms; animation-delay: 123ms; }
.delay-2 { -webkit-animation-delay: 2023ms; animation-delay: 2023ms; }
.delay-3 { -webkit-animation-delay: 773ms; animation-delay: 773ms; }
.delay-4 { -webkit-animation-delay: 1123ms; animation-delay: 1123ms; }
```

Comment: You would probably want to use `backface-visibility: hidden;`.

Comment: How about 2 planes, one for the upwards motion (which then vanishes at top point), one for the down (which then appears). One of them is created before the Sphere, one after.

Comment: @Ian I did that, the hard part is getting the backside to sync perfectly with the front side in terms of animation timing. Do you know a trick for this? animation-delay doesn't cut it because it just delays the first run

Comment: You could combine with a blink effect, eg http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbBMmp

Comment: Btw, you may want to check browser support for css transformations on svg (I think IE10 and below doesn't support it, but I may be wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is difficult without some extra elements or javascript I think.

You could do this, by adding a 2nd mirror element, one created earlier in the DOM that the circle, so it appears behind it. At the same time, make the front plane vanish when trying to give the appearance it is behind.

So to make the front plane vanish...

```
<pre><code>
@keyframes blink {  
  0% { opacity: 1.0; }
  50% { opacity: 0.0; }
  100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  0% { opacity: 1.0; }
  50% { opacity: 0.0; }
  100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}
.blink {
  animation: blink 2500ms step-start 0s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: blink 2500ms step-start 0s infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 400ms; 
  animation-delay: 400ms;
} 

...

    <g class="plane-container" transform="rotate(0)">
      <use class="plane" xlink:href="#svg-plane" width="50" height="50"></use>
    </g>

    <circle class="globe" cx="0" cy="0" r="100" />

    <g class="plane-container blink" transform="rotate(0)">
      <use class="plane" xlink:href="#svg-plane" width="50" height="50"></use>
    </g>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbBMmp)

Just check browser support that you need, especially in IE for svg+css3 transform support

Answer (score 0):

I think dummy loop and relative timing is helpful. See [How to make SVG Loop Animation?](http://codepen.io/danjiro/blog/how-to-make-svg-loop-animation)

```html
<svg>
  <rect>
    <animate id="o1" begin="0;o1.end" dur="10s"
    attributeName="visibility" from="hide" to="hide"/>
  </rect>
  <circle fill="orange" cx="-50" cy="100" r="20">
    <animate begin="o1.begin" 
    attributeName="cx" from="250" to="50" dur="5.05s"/>
  </circle>
  <circle fill="blue" cx="150" cy="100" r="50" />
  <circle fill="orange" cx="-50" cy="100" r="20">
    <animate begin="o1.begin+5s" 
    attributeName="cx" from="50" to="250" dur="5.05s"/>
  </circle>
</svg>
```